# deploy flask app on Google App Engine - 500 Bad Gateway

Tags: flask, google-app-engine, deployment, python-3.10

I'm facing an issue with concurrent sessions in my Flask app. The app connects to an ElephantSQL database. Everything works fine on my local machine, but when I deployed the app (on Google App Engine), I started encountering a problem. Whenever I try to access the database quickly after a few seconds, I get 500 internal error.
I have a hunch that this error is somehow related to pending sessions, but I can't quite pinpoint the exact glitch. I even tried rolling back, but it didn't solve the problem. What's interesting is that the error disappears if I give the database some rest and don't send any requests for a while. But as soon as I try to access it again, the issue resurfaces.
Appreciate any help or suggestions on this.

This is the log of my error:

```
insertId: 64a2f1d600041488a3de5e42
labels:
clone_id: 00c61b117c382bb99af50d2674addce8172fccda10378193633e26cf7b391635e0c587ab4983c8a4acd26dd524cafa59bb100c2489cc1637fcaa
logName: projects/moviesbox-391505/logs/stderr
receiveTimestamp: '2023-07-03T16:05:42.322972285Z'
resource:
labels:
  module_id: default
  project_id: moviesbox-391505
  version_id: 20230703t154917
  zone: us-west1-4
type: gae_app
severity: ERROR
textPayload: |-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1482, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1974, in preprocess_request
    rv = self.ensure_sync(before_func)()
  File "/workspace/app.py", line 41, in add_user_to_g
    g.user = User.query.get(session[CURR_USER_KEY])
  File "<string>", line 2, in get
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 386, in warned
timestamp: '2023-07-03T16:05:42.267400Z'
```

and this is the part related to the add* user to g function in my app.py*

```
CURR_USER_KEY = "curr_user"
```

```
app = Flask(__name__)
load_dotenv()

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = get_secret("DATABASE_URL")
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
app.config['DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = get_secret('SECRET_KEY')
# toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)

app.app_context().push()
connect_db(app)



# Create a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Set the logging level to ERROR
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

##############################################################################
# User signup/login/logout routes
##############################################################################

@app.before_request
def add_user_to_g():
    """ If logged in, add curr user to Flask global. """

    if CURR_USER_KEY in session:
        try:
            g.user = User.query.get(session[CURR_USER_KEY])

        # Catch any exceptions for now
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"An error has occurred: {e}", exc_info=True)
        

    else:
        g.user = None
```

I don't know if it is something to the environment config of my deployment, database issue or flask session issue.